# How to remove localization in Firebug

Tags: internationalization, firebug

After last Firebug update all labels get translated to French but I didn't ask about it. And I really can't get rid of that. I am in France now, but all my locales, all preferences are set to English (Great Britain), only timezone is set to (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris. At the same time I have English version of the Firefox.

P.S. It really drives me crazy. Does anybody know how to force Firebug to use only English and never translate to any other language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed now. In fact, I did nothing. I had 10.0.3 (ESR) version of FireFox. After I updated to 10.0.6 the bug disappears. Firebug version remains the same 1.9.2.

Answer (score 2):

For Firebug in particular, setting extensions.firebug.useDefaultLocale to true should help.

Comment: Firebug menus are now translated to English but content in the table still in French. Perhaps, it's Firebug localization bug.

Answer (score 0):

[Quick Locale Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quick-locale-switcher/?src=search) worked for me.

Comment: This plugin changes accept_language and general.useragent.locale which are set to en-GB in my case already. I've checked different options in about:config and they all set to en-GB. So this is not helpful for me (

Comment: Interesting fact is that Quick Locale Switcher is translated to French itself when all global configurations of Firefox are set to English.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. I'm using Firebug 1.9.2 with Firefox 12 on Mac OS X. Quick Locale Switcher changes general.useragent.locale to en-US from the default ja-JP-mac and it definitely changes the user interface of Firebug from Japanese to English.

Comment: I've tried to change general.useragent.locale manually with restarting Firefox, but it doesn't work. Regardless what is set for that preference Firebug still showing me everything translated to French. Seems I should move on somewhere from France to get that problem fixed )